# What Stack Exchange site is appropriate for asking where a movie can be found for streaming?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've not been able to find a particular movie, and I can't figure out which site this is appropriate for.

I already tried the Movies & TV site but it was off topic there. Is there a SE site where this is appropriate or do I need to find another place entirely?

Answer (score 11):

Generally - recommending other resources aren't great fits for SE sites, especially with where to legally stream things, where its currently a crazy patchwork of competing services.

More or less, unfortunately, this is not one of the things we are good at

Comment: Shame. I've been trying to find something. :(

Answer (score 11):

You would get more timely and accurate information about what content is available from which service by using a site like [ReelGood](https://reelgood.com/) or [JustWatch](https://www.justwatch.com/).

Streaming content changes all the time, and what’s not available today may be available next week, so those sorts of questions don’t really fit on a site that is trying to build a reference library of answers that will be valid far into the future.

Comment: I've been trying to find somewhere to stream https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Herbert%27s_Dune , I haven't seen it in years and have had no luck finding somewhere :( Whether for free or buying it

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be available anywhere right now @Hematita. You might be able to find a used copy of the DVD somewhere. Sites like ReelGood might also notify you if it becomes available, but there’s no guarantee it ever will.